# Dynamic of the content of a certain cell (using NotebookRead)

Tags: functions, function-construction, dynamic, notebooks, cells

Initial state :

```
Cell[BoxData["123"], "Output", CellTags -> "ImdaK"] // CellPrint
123

Dynamic[NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> "ImdaK"][[1]]][[1, 1]]]
123
```

Then I changed the cell with CellTags "ImdaK" with 12345.

But the output

```
Dynamic[NotebookRead[Cells[CellTags -> "ImdaK"][[1]]][[1, 1]]]
```

remained unchanged. It was always 123.

[image]

I know that `Dynamic` doesn't work in some subtle situation.

How to make `Dynamic` work OK for `NotebookRead` ?

Update period of Dynamic doesn't need to be real-time. (every 1 second update is acceptable)

Comment: You should look at the docs for `Refresh`.

Comment: Thank you, the function was so useful. It allows us to use Dynamic[] more dynamically.